# Issue with saving backup files

Tags: linux

Please help to understand how I can do this.
I created the script which do backup of database every hour.
And to this script need to add function which delete old files, but :
Need to stay one backup which created in previous month, one from previous week and two last backups from this day. Others must be deleted.

How i can do this?
thanks.

P.S. there is exmaple format of name files :

```
"$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M")"-cacti_db.sql.gz
```

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: I using mysql database